# How to make several comboboxes dependent and show only relative options?

Tags: excel, vba

This is my second day working with Excel VBA and I have to finish an application for reporting manpower needed tomorrow after being failed by some workmates. I had to read hundreds of tutorials and watch tens of videos to reach this point of building this application so far but I still have some issues to solve. The idea of the application is to have a userform that opens once the workbook is opened. There is 5 cobmoboxes for the selection criteria (Function, Location, Technology, Work Pattern and Operating conditions) respectively. The 2nd combobox is dependent on the 1st and the 3rd is dependent on the 2nd. The 4th and 5th are dependent on the 1st combobox and it is working fine. The problem is with the 3rd combobox because it shows all the options regardless of the choice made in the 2nd combobox because of case selection reads numbers only!

Here is the code:

```
    Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

Dim index As Integer
index = ComboBox1.ListIndex

ComboBox2.Clear

Select Case index
    Case Is = 0
        With ComboBox2
            .AddItem "Location 1"
            .AddItem "Location 2"
            .AddItem "Location 3"
            .AddItem "Location 4"
        End With
    Case Is = 1
        With ComboBox2
            .AddItem "Location 1"
            .AddItem "Location 2"
            .AddItem "Location 3"
        End With
    Case Is = 2
        With ComboBox2
            .AddItem "Location 1"
            .AddItem "Location 2"
            .AddItem "Location 3"
        End With
    Case Is = 3
        With ComboBox2
            .AddItem "Location 1"
            .AddItem "Location 2"
            .AddItem "Location 3"
        .AddItem "Location 4"
        End With
    Case Is = 4
        With ComboBox2
            .AddItem "Location 1"
            .AddItem "Location 2"
            .AddItem "Location 3"
        .AddItem "Location 4"

        End With
End Select

ComboBox4.Clear

Select Case index
    Case Is = 0
        With ComboBox4
            .AddItem "8 Hours"
            .AddItem "12 Hours"

        End With
End Select

ComboBox5.Clear

Select Case index
    Case Is = 0
        With ComboBox5
            .AddItem "Low Speed"
            .AddItem "Normal Speed"
            .AddItem "High Speed"
        End With

     Case Is = 2
        With ComboBox5
            .AddItem "Drips"
            .AddItem "Pivots"
        End With

End Select

End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox2_Change()
Dim index As Integer
index = ComboBox2.ListIndex

ComboBox3.Clear

Select Case index
    Case Is = 0
        With ComboBox3
            .AddItem "Line 1"
            .AddItem "Line 2"
            .AddItem "Line 3"
            .AddItem "Line 4"
            .AddItem "Line 5"


        End With

    Case Is = 1
        With ComboBox3
            .AddItem "Line 1"
            .AddItem "Line 2"
            .AddItem "Line 3"
            .AddItem "Line 4"

        End With

    Case Is = 2
        With ComboBox3
            .AddItem "Line 1"
            .AddItem "Line 2"

        End With

    Case Is = 3
        With ComboBox3
            .AddItem "Line 1"
            .AddItem "Line 2"
            .AddItem "Line 3"
            .AddItem "Line 4"

        End With
End Select

End Sub


Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

With ComboBox1
    .AddItem "Function 1"
    .AddItem "Function 2"
    .AddItem "Function 3"
    .AddItem "Function 4"
    .AddItem "Function 5"
End With


End Sub
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I assume “I have to finish an application for reporting manpower needed tomorrow” means your boss wants you to create a macro NOW even though you have no relevant experience.  I am pleased you have tried the many tutorials but there is no substitute for practice.

To test your code, I created a new workbook with a new user form on which I created five combo boxes which I left with the default names as you have.  I copied in your code which worked for me.  I get different options in ComboBox3 according to the selection within ComboBox2.  You will need to be more specific about what is not working as you expect.

However, I am going to suggest some changes.  You are working to a deadline so this may seem a bad idea but my experience is that the changes I suggest will save time.  They may save time today because the changes will make it easier to debug your macro.  They will certainly save time next week when your boss comes back with a long list of changes.

Combo boxes allow the user to type their own value.  List boxes are similar to combo boxes but the user can only chose from the options provided.  I do not recall every using combo boxes because I have never needed the functionality although I can appreciate that it could be useful in the right situation.  I prefer list boxes anyway because the options are always visible if the box is big enough.  Perhaps there is a trick I have never discovered but I can only see the options within a combo box when I click the box.

I deleted the five combo boxes and replaced them with five list boxes each about five lines deep so all the options would be visible.  I renamed `ListBox1` as `ComboBox1`, `ListBox2` as `ComboBox2` and so on.  I do not recommend this but it meant I could use your code unchanged.  I could click an option in box1 and see the options in the other boxes.  Click again and see another set of options.  As I said, your code appears to do what you want.

I then renamed your boxes: `lstFunction`, `lstLocation`, `lstTechnology`, `lstPattern` and `lstConditions`.  I remember when having a three character prefixes indicating the type was common for all variables.  This practice has largely died out for variables but not so much for user form controls.  I used them here because `Function` is a reserved word and cannot be used as a name.  I used global replace (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+H) in the code to replace `ComboBox1` with `lstFunction` and so on.

The advantage of meaningful names is that code is so much more readable.  You may remember that Box3 is Technology today but will you remember when you return to this macro is six or twelve months?

I have replaced `Integer` by `Long`.  `Integer` defines a sixteen bit, two byte variable that can hold a value in the range -32,768 to 32,767.  This was fine when VBA was first introduced but has two major disadvantages now.  (1) The range is too small for today’s Excel.  (2) Sixteen bit numbers require special (slow) processing on 32 and 64-bit computers.

Lastly I replaced `index (= ComboBox1.ListIndex)` with `ComboBox1.Value`.  You seem to think that `Case` only works with numbers.  This is not true.  To be honest, I would prefer to get these values from a hidden worksheet since I find worksheets easier to maintain than code but perhaps you should leave that until next week.

This is my final code:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub lstFunction_Change()

Dim index As Long
index = lstFunction.ListIndex

lstLocation.Clear

Select Case lstFunction.Value
    Case Is = "Function 1"
        With lstLocation
            .AddItem "Location 1"
            .AddItem "Location 2"
            .AddItem "Location 3"
            .AddItem "Location 4"
        End With
    Case Is = "Function 2"
        With lstLocation
            .AddItem "Location 1"
            .AddItem "Location 2"
            .AddItem "Location 3"
        End With
    Case Is = "Function 3"
        With lstLocation
            .AddItem "Location 1"
            .AddItem "Location 2"
            .AddItem "Location 3"
        End With
    Case Is = "Function 4"
        With lstLocation
            .AddItem "Location 1"
            .AddItem "Location 2"
            .AddItem "Location 3"
        .AddItem "Location 4"
        End With
    Case Is = "Function 5"
        With lstLocation
            .AddItem "Location 1"
            .AddItem "Location 2"
            .AddItem "Location 3"
        .AddItem "Location 4"

        End With
End Select

lstPattern.Clear

Select Case lstFunction
    Case Is = "Function 1"
        With lstPattern
            .AddItem "8 Hours"
            .AddItem "12 Hours"

        End With
End Select

lstConditions.Clear

Select Case lstFunction
    Case Is = "Function 1"
        With lstConditions
            .AddItem "Low Speed"
            .AddItem "Normal Speed"
            .AddItem "High Speed"
        End With

     Case Is = "Function 3"
        With lstConditions
            .AddItem "Drips"
            .AddItem "Pivots"
        End With

End Select

End Sub

Private Sub lstLocation_Change()
Dim index As Long
index = lstLocation.ListIndex

lstTechnology.Clear

Select Case lstLocation.Value
    Case Is = "Location 1"
        With lstTechnology
            .AddItem "Line 1"
            .AddItem "Line 2"
            .AddItem "Line 3"
            .AddItem "Line 4"
            .AddItem "Line 5"


        End With

    Case Is = "Location 2"
        With lstTechnology
            .AddItem "Line 1"
            .AddItem "Line 2"
            .AddItem "Line 3"
            .AddItem "Line 4"

        End With

    Case Is = "Location 3"
        With lstTechnology
            .AddItem "Line 1"
            .AddItem "Line 2"

        End With

    Case Is = "Location 4"
        With lstTechnology
            .AddItem "Line 1"
            .AddItem "Line 2"
            .AddItem "Line 3"
            .AddItem "Line 4"

        End With
End Select

End Sub


Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

With lstFunction
    .AddItem "Function 1"
    .AddItem "Function 2"
    .AddItem "Function 3"
    .AddItem "Function 4"
    .AddItem "Function 5"
End With


End Sub
```

Comment: Well it works just perfect..i dont know if i can ask how to use if-statements with these combination of comboboxes or shall i post another separate question?

Comment: Do you mean: `If lstFunction.Value = "Function 1" Then` ... `ElseIf lstFunction.Value = "Function 2"` Then ... `ElseIf lstFunction.Value = "Function 3"` ... `End If`. `If ... IfElse ... IfElse ... End If` is very useful when you are a list of different conditions to check but I do not believe it offers any advantage when you are testing which of a list of different values matches a single variable.

Answer (score 0):

I created a blank workbook and ran your code as you presented it. I had no issues with ComboBox3 as is demonstrated by the image below.

[image: ComboBox3]

Answer (score 0):

In my first answer, I said “To be honest, I would prefer to get these values from a hidden worksheet since I find worksheets easier to maintain than code but perhaps you should leave that until next week.”  Your question about `If` statements suggests you are unhappy about your current approach.  I would agree with that unhappiness; getting code like this correct and maintaining it as new options and new links are introduced is at best difficult and can be near impossible.

I find it easier to define and maintain such links in a worksheet.  It is probably best if the worksheet is hidden although the information it contains is not secret.  Consider:

```
  |     A     |      B      |      C      |     D    |      E      |
  |-----------|-------------|-------------|----------|-------------|
1 |lstFunction|lstLocation  |lstTechnology|lstPattern|lstConditions|
  |-----------|-------------|-------------|----------|-------------|
2 |Function 1 |Location 1   |             |8 Hours   |Low Speed    |
  |           |Location 2   |             |12 Hours  |Normal Speed |
  |           |Location 3   |             |          |High Speed   |
  |           |Location 4   |             |          |             |
  |-----------|-------------|-------------|----------|-------------|
3 |Function 2 |Location 1   |             |          |             |
  |           |Location 2   |             |          |             |
  |           |Location 3   |             |          |             |
  |-----------|-------------|-------------|----------|-------------|
4 |Function 3 |Location 1   |             |          |Drips        |
  |           |Location 2   |             |          |Pivots       |
  |           |Location 3   |             |          |             |
  |-----------|-------------|-------------|----------|-------------|
5 |Function 4 |Location 1   |             |          |             |
  |           |Location 2   |             |          |             |
  |           |Location 3   |             |          |             |
  |-----------|-------------|-------------|----------|-------------|
6 |Function 5 |Location 1   |             |          |             |
  |           |Location 2   |             |          |             |
  |           |Location 3   |             |          |             |
  |-----------|-------------|-------------|----------|-------------|
7 |           |             |             |          |             |
  |-----------|-------------|-------------|----------|-------------|
8 |lstLocation|lstTechnology|             |          |             |
  |-----------|-------------|-------------|----------|-------------|
9 |Location 1 |Line 1       |             |          |             |
  |           |Line 2       |             |          |             |
  |           |Line 3       |             |          |             |
  |           |Line 4       |             |          |             |
  |           |Line 5       |             |          |             |
  |-----------|-------------|-------------|----------|-------------|
10|Location 2 |Line 1       |             |          |             |
  |           |Line 2       |             |          |             |
  |           |Line 3       |             |          |             |
  |           |Line 4       |             |          |             |
  |-----------|-------------|-------------|----------|-------------|
11|Location 3 |Line 1       |             |          |             |
  |           |Line 2       |             |          |             |
  |-----------|-------------|-------------|----------|-------------|
12|Location 4 |Line 1       |             |          |             |
  |           |Line 2       |             |          |             |
  |           |Line 3       |             |          |             |
  |           |Line 4       |             |          |             |
  |-----------|-------------|-------------|----------|-------------|
```

Rows 1 to 6 and 8 to 12 each define a table that links the permitted values of the controlling list box named in column A to the permitted values of the dependent list boxes named in columns B, C and so on.

A table is terminated by a blank cell in column A.

The first row of a table lists the names of the list boxes.  The remaining rows of a table list the relationships between permitted values.  Column A contains all permitted values of the controlling list box.  For example, cells A2 to A6 contain all permitted values for list box `lstFunction`.  The cells in columns B, C and so on list the permitted values for the dependent list boxes if value in column A is selected by the user.  For example, if the user selects the value in cell A2 (“Function 1”), cell B2 lists the four permitted values for dependent control `lstLocation` separated by linefeeds.  If a cell is blank, for example C3, the dependent control has no permitted values.

Note that a blank cell (for example, C2, D3 and E5) means the dependent control is cleared without being reloaded.  I notice that if you select a new value for `lstFunction` you do not clear `lstTechnology` although you do clear `lstPattern` and `lstConditions`.  I suspect that was a mistake.

I say “list box” in the above description even though the code would work for combo boxes but I do not see how the concept of linked boxes can apply to combo boxes.  If the user enters a new value for a controlling combo box, what is to happen to its dependent controls?

There is no limit to the number of linkages that can be defined.  I hope you agree that a table like this is easier to create and maintain correctly than the type of code you have been writing.  The code to process this table will be more complicated to write than your current code.  The advantages of the code I will introduce include:

1. Once the code is written you can add more controls and more linkages just by updating the table.
2. You can move the code to another workbook or run it off a different form for very little effort.
3. My code may be more complicated that your approach with 5 list boxes and 2 sets of linkages but your code will get more and more complicated as you increase the number of list boxes and linkages while my code will remain unchanged.

To understand my code, you need to understand the Controls collection for a user form.  Add the following code to your `UserForm_Initialize()` routine:

```
  Dim InxC As Long

  For InxC = 0 To Controls.Count - 1
    Debug.Print InxC & " " & TypeName(Controls(InxC))
    With Controls(InxC)
      Debug.Print "  Name=" & .Name & "  Top=" & .Top & _
                  "  Left=" & .Left & "  Height=" & .Height & _
                  "  Width=" & .Width
    End With
  Next

  Debug.Print "lstFunction " & TypeName(Controls("lstFunction"))
```

With my form, the output is:

```
0 ListBox
  Name=lstFunction  Top=18  Left=18  Height=61.5  Width=102
1 ListBox
  Name=lstLocation  Top=18  Left=144  Height=66  Width=90
2 ListBox
  Name=lstTechnology  Top=18  Left=258  Height=66  Width=96
3 ListBox
  Name=lstPattern  Top=18  Left=378  Height=66  Width=96
4 ListBox
  Name=lstConditions  Top=18  Left=492  Height=66  Width=90
5 CommandButton
  Name=btnExit  Top=96  Left=18  Height=24  Width=72
lstFunction ListBox
```

Every form has a collection named `Controls` that contains every control on that form.  My code loops displaying details of every control by its index number.  The details I show are type name, name, position and size but every parameter of the control can be accessed this way.  Lastly, I display the type of a control using its name.

What I am trying to show is that instead of writing `lstFunction.Value` I can write `Controls(0).Value` or `Controls("lstFunction").Value`.  This allows me to code one general routine for all controls rather than writing specific code for each control.

Another facility you may not have encountered yet is that an entire worksheet (on just part) can be imported in a single statement with:

```
Variable = Range.Value
```

`Variable` must be of type `Variant` and `Range` must be specified to match the area of the worksheet you wish to import.

I considered processing the imported worksheet to structure the data but I do not think it will offer any advantages.  However, I believed it would be worth identifying the start of each sub-table (A1 and A8) so they could be located easily.

Without risking missing any deadlines, I suggest you work through the code below which achieves the same as your original code.  I avoid explaining the VBA statements since they are easy to look up once you know they exist.  I explain the objective of each block of code.  Come back with questions as necessary.

My code expects to find worksheet “Links” containing link tables as defined above.  It expects the form to contain list boxes named: `lstFunction`, `lstLocation`, `lstTechnology`, `lstPattern` and `lstConditions` and a command button named `btnExit`.  You can change these names to match your requirements.

```
Option Explicit

  ' Global variants available to any routine in this userform code module.

  ' These variables are initialised by UserForm_Initialize()
  Dim Links As Variant                 ' The worksheet is imported to this Variant
  Dim LinksFirstRows() As Long         ' Element N contains the top row within Links of the Nth table
  Dim DependentControl() As Boolean    ' Element N is True if the control from the Nth table is dependent on another control

  ' Clearing a list box can call its change event routine.  While this variable is True, any change
  ' event routine exits immediately to avoid routines being called and recalled.
  Dim WithinChange As Boolean
Private Sub btnExit_Click()

  Unload Me

End Sub
Private Sub lstFunction_Change()

  ' During development of a new form, I ususally plant statements like this throughtout my code.
  ' If an event routine for one control updates another control, event routines for the second control
  ' may be called.  I use these statements to track the path through the various routines.
  Debug.Print "Enter lstFunction"

  If WithinChange Then
    Debug.Print "Immediate exit lstFunction"
    Exit Sub
  End If

  Call UpdateBoxes("lstFunction")

  Debug.Print "Exit lstFunction"

End Sub
Private Sub lstLocation_Change()

  Debug.Print "Enter lstLocation"

  If WithinChange Then
    Debug.Print "Immediate exit lstLocation"
    Exit Sub
  End If

  Call UpdateBoxes("lstLocation")

  Debug.Print "Exit lstLocation"

End Sub
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

  Dim ColCrnt As Long
  Dim ColLast As Long
  Dim InxTableCrnt As Long
  Dim InxTableCheck As Long
  Dim NameCrnt As String
  Dim RowCrnt As Long
  Dim RowLast As Long

  Debug.Print "Enter UserForm_Initialize"

  ' Change "Links" to your name for the worksheet containing the links.
  ' My data matches the table at the top of my answer.
  With Worksheets("Links")
    ' There are several methods of finding the last row and column of a worksheet.
    ' This method is appropriate when the data is not rectangular so there is no
    ' bottom, right cell.
    RowLast = .Cells.Find("*", .Range("A1"), xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
    ColLast = .Cells.Find("*", .Range("A1"), xlFormulas, , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Column
    ' Import range of interest
    Links = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(RowLast, ColLast)).Value
  End With

  ' Within a 2D array, it is standard to have the columns as the first dimension and
  ' the rows as the second dimension.  Arrays imported from a worksheet or being
  ' prepared for export to a worksheet have their dimensions the other way round.

  ' An array imported from a worksheet always has lower bounds of 1.  Since the area loaded
  ' starts from Cells(1, 1), the row and column numbers in Links matches those in the
  ' worksheet.  This can help during debugging.

  ' Find and record the top row of each table within the worksheet
  RowCrnt = 1
  Do While RowCrnt <= RowLast         ' Loop for each table
    If RowCrnt = 1 Then
      ' First entries in LinksFirstRows and DependentControl
      ReDim LinksFirstRows(1 To 1)
      ReDim DependentControl(1 To 1)
      LinksFirstRows(1) = 1
      DependentControl(1) = False        ' Assume not dependent until find otherwise
    Else
      ' Not first entries in LinksFirstRows and DependentControl
      ' ReDim Preserve is a very useful command but the more it is used the slower it becomes.
      ' Each ReDim requires the interpreter: (1) find a block of memory big enough for
      ' the enlarged array, (2) copy values from the old array, (3) release the old array
      ' for garbage collection.  Even with 20 or 30 controlling list boxes this would not be
      ' a problem for this macro but code can slow to a stand still with enough ReDim Preserves.
      ReDim Preserve LinksFirstRows(1 To UBound(LinksFirstRows) + 1)
      ReDim Preserve DependentControl(1 To UBound(DependentControl) + 1)
      LinksFirstRows(UBound(LinksFirstRows)) = RowCrnt
      DependentControl(UBound(DependentControl)) = False
    End If
    Do While RowCrnt < RowLast         ' Loop looking for blank line
      RowCrnt = RowCrnt + 1
      If Links(RowCrnt, 1) = "" Then
        Exit Do
      End If
    Loop
    RowCrnt = RowCrnt + 1   ' Step over blank line terminating table
  Loop

  ' Identify and record tables which are dependent on another and which are not
  For InxTableCrnt = 1 To UBound(LinksFirstRows)

    RowCrnt = LinksFirstRows(InxTableCrnt)

    ColCrnt = 2
    Do While Links(RowCrnt, ColCrnt) <> ""    ' Loop for each dependent list box of current table
      ' Check the name of the dependent list box (in Links(RowCrnt, ColCrnt)) against the
      ' name of each controlling list box (in Links(LinksFirstRows(InxTableCheck), 1)).
      ' If they match table InxTableCheck is dependent on table InxTableCrnt.
      ' Note, I do not record the controlling table; just that table InxTableCheck is dependent on another
      NameCrnt = Links(RowCrnt, ColCrnt)            ' Name of dependent control
      For InxTableCheck = 1 To UBound(LinksFirstRows)
        If NameCrnt = Links(LinksFirstRows(InxTableCheck), 1) Then
          DependentControl(InxTableCheck) = True
          Exit For
        End If
      Next
      ColCrnt = ColCrnt + 1
      ' The dependent controls for at least one table will extend to the last column of Links.
      ' This check avoids an out of bounds error when Links(RowCrnt, ColCrnt) is checked.
      If ColCrnt > UBound(Links, 2) Then
        Exit Do
      End If
    Loop

  Next

  ' Build list boxes that are not dependent on other list boxes

  WithinChange = True           ' So the Change event routines exit immediately as their list boxes are built
  Debug.Print "WithinChange = True"

  For InxTableCrnt = 1 To UBound(LinksFirstRows)
    If Not DependentControl(InxTableCrnt) Then
      ' The controlling list box for this table is not dependent on another
      ' so load it
      RowCrnt = LinksFirstRows(InxTableCrnt)
      NameCrnt = Links(RowCrnt, 1)              ' Name of controlling list box
      RowCrnt = RowCrnt + 1
      Do While Links(RowCrnt, 1) <> ""
        Controls(NameCrnt).AddItem (Links(RowCrnt, 1))
        RowCrnt = RowCrnt + 1
      Loop
     End If
  Next

  WithinChange = False
  Debug.Print "WithinChange = False"

  Debug.Print "Exit UserForm_Initialize"


End Sub
Sub UpdateBoxes(ByVal CtrlName As String)

  ' CtrlName is the name of a box control for which the user has select a value or a new value.
  ' The permitted values for other box controls depend on that value.
  ' Clear the current content of the dependent boxes and load with new values, if appropriate.
  ' If CtrlName cannot be found or if the current value cannot be found, this routine exits
  ' without chnaging any list box.

  Dim BoxValues() As String
  Dim ColCrnt As Long
  Dim InxBoxValue As Long
  Dim InxTableCrnt As Long
  Dim RowCrnt As Long
  Dim RowTop As Long
  Dim ValueCrnt As String

  ' Search for a table for CtrlName
  For InxTableCrnt = 1 To UBound(LinksFirstRows)
    RowCrnt = LinksFirstRows(InxTableCrnt)
    If Links(RowCrnt, 1) = CtrlName Then
      ' Have found the correct table.
      RowTop = RowCrnt
      RowCrnt = RowCrnt + 1
      ValueCrnt = Controls(CtrlName).Value
      ' look for current value.
      Do While Links(RowCrnt, 1) <> ""
        If ValueCrnt = Links(RowCrnt, 1) Then
          ' Have required table and required value
          For ColCrnt = 2 To UBound(Links, 2)
            If Links(RowTop, ColCrnt) = "" Then
              ' No more dependent list boxes for this controlling list box
              Exit For
            End If

            WithinChange = True           ' So the Change event routines exit immediately as their list boxes are built
            Debug.Print "WithinChange = True"

            With Controls(Links(RowTop, ColCrnt))
              .Clear
              If Links(RowCrnt, ColCrnt) <> "" Then
                ' There are new values for this list box
                BoxValues = Split(Links(RowCrnt, ColCrnt), vbLf)
                For InxBoxValue = LBound(BoxValues) To UBound(BoxValues)
                  .AddItem (BoxValues(InxBoxValue))
                Next InxBoxValue
              End If
            End With

            WithinChange = False
            Debug.Print "WithinChange = False"

          Next ColCrnt
          Exit Do
        End If
        RowCrnt = RowCrnt + 1
      Loop

      Exit For
    End If

  Next InxTableCrnt

End Sub
```